Запуск двух скриптов параллельно Python
Подскажите пожалуйста. У меня есть два разных файла скрипта Python. Первый файл фласк сервер, второй TCP сервер. Фласк скрипт - основной файл. При включенном параметре, при запуске фласка из этого же скрипта должен запускаться второй скрипт TCP сервер. Но так как TCP скрипт бесконечный, через subprocess у меня не получилось сделать или я не понял как. Задача просто запустить этот скрипт и не отслеживать его дальше, чтобы он работал сам по себе так сказать. Что делать?
server flask
#!/usr/bin/sudo python

import time
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse
import socket
import os
import json
import requests
import logging
from cysystemd import journal
import subprocess
import threading

app = Flask(__name__)


class LoggingSystem:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = logging.getLogger('ITCService')
        self.log.addHandler(journal.JournaldLogHandler())
        self.log.setLevel(logging.INFO)


def run_online_locks_server():
    subprocess.Popen(

        ['python', 'init.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE
    )


def check_system_conf():
    start_data = {
        "host_address_ip": '192.168.0.19',
        "host_address_port": 8181,
        "club_software_login": "skud",
        "club_software_pass": "skud1234",
        "club_software_url": "192.168.88.70/skud/",
        "online_locks_port": 9191,
        "online_locks_enable": 1,
        "online_locks_conf": {
            "women": {
                "quantity_locks": 48,
                "hosts_ip_address": ["192.168.0.178"],
                "hosts_port_address": 5001
            },
            "man": {
                "quantity_locks": 48,
                "hosts_ip_address": ["192.168.0.178"],
                "hosts_port_address": 5001
            },
        },
        "debug_flag_enable": 0
    }
    if os.path.isdir('/etc/itclocks'):
        if os.path.exists('/etc/itclocks/itclocks.json'):
            pass
        else:
            file = open('/etc/itclocks/itclocks.json', 'w')
            json.dump(start_data, file, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
            file.close()
    else:
        os.mkdir('/etc/itclocks')
        file = open('/etc/itclocks/itclocks.json', 'w')
        json.dump(start_data, file, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
        file.close()
    return load_config_data()


def load_config_data():
    file = open('/etc/itclocks/itclocks.json', 'r')
    data = json.load(file)
    return data


@app.route("/unlock_all", methods=['GET'])
def open_all_locks():
    client.send('unlock_all'.encode('utf-8'))


@app.route("/check_status", methods=['GET'])
def check_status():
    print('1')
    client.send('check_status'.encode('utf-8'))
    run_listen = True
    while run_listen:
        data = client.recv(512)
        if len(data) == 0:
            pass
        else:
            print(data)
            run_listen = False


@app.route("/unlock_lock", methods=['POST'])
def open_lock():
    data1 = request.get_json()
    client.send("unlock_lock".encode('utf-8'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_online_locks = True
    system_data_conf = check_system_conf()
    if system_data_conf["online_locks_enable"] == 1:
        for i in range(3):
            try:
                run_online_locks_server()
                time.sleep(3)
                client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                client.connect(('192.168.0.19', 10000))
                break
            except Exception as error:
                print(error)
                time.sleep(2)

    app.run(threaded=True, debug=True, host=system_data_conf['host_address_ip'],
            port=system_data_conf['host_address_port'])

TCP Server
#!/usr/bin/sudo python

import socket

print('fff')
server_cu = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_cu.connect(('192.168.0.178', 5000))
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server.bind(('192.168.0.19', 10001))
server.listen()
conn, addr = server.accept()


def ask_state():
    cmd = [0x02, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x50, 0x03, 0x5F]
    server_cu.send(bytes(cmd))


def process_state(data=None):
    print(data)
    if data is None:
        print("empty packet")
        return False
    if len(data) != 12:
        print("Packet length mismatch")
    if data[0] != 0x02 or data[2] != 0x00 or data[3] != 0x65 or data[10] != 0x03:
        print("invalid packet")
        return False
    board_number = data[1]
    lock_number = 1
    states = []
    for byte_num in range(4, 10):
        for bit_num in range(0, 8):
            state = 1 if data[byte_num] & (1 << bit_num) > 0 else 0
            print(f"B:{board_number}, L{lock_number}, S{state}")
            states.append([board_number, lock_number, state])
            lock_number += 1
    return str(states)


def unlock_all():
    cmd = [0x02, 0x00, 0x30, 0x51, 0x03, 0x86]
    server_cu.send(bytes(cmd))


while True:
    print(2)
    conn, addr = server.accept()
    print(3)
    while True:
        print(4)
        datagram = conn.recv(512)
        print(5)
        if not datagram:
            break
        if datagram == b'check_status':
            cmd = [0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x50, 0x03, 0x55]
            ask_state()
            states = None
            data_recv = 0
            while states is None:
                print(9)
                data_recv = server_cu.recv(512)
                print(10)
                if len(data_recv) == 12:
                    print(11)
                    states = False
            print(data_recv)
            conn.send(data_recv)

        if datagram == b'unlock_all':
            print(6)
            unlock_all()

        if b'unlock_lock' in datagram:
            cmd = [0x02, 0x00, 0x30, 0x51, 0x03, 0x86]
            server_cu.send(bytes(cmd))
        conn.sendall(''.encode('utf-8'))
    server.close()


Задавая вопрос, Вы должны прикладывать код, чтоб было видно как пытались это решить и что делали не так.

В чем проблема запустить отдельно скрипт? Не из вашего фласк приложения?

В общем нашел решение проблемы, я раскидал каждый из скриптов по отдельным папкам(просто ради красоты))), создал третий скрипт, основной и через треды запустил сначала TCP сервер, потом flask сервер. Все отлично работает!
def start_cu_server():
    os.system(f'python Olock/main.py')


def start_flask_server():
    os.system(f'python Flask/main.py')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    log = start_logging()
    system_data_conf = check_system_conf()
    path = "pythonProject/"
    abs_path = os.path.abspath(path)
    print(abs_path)
    if system_data_conf["online_locks_enable"]:
        locks_table = check_table_locks()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=start_cu_server)
        thread.start()
    start_flask_server()


Использование subprocess
def run_online_locks_server():
    try:
        process = subprocess.Popen(
            # Убедитесь, что относительный путь к init.py правильный
            ['python', 'init.py'],  # можно указать полный путь
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE
        )

        # Если вы хотите отладить, что происходит при запуске,
        # вы можете добавить вывод ошибок в стандартный вывод:
        stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Произошла ошибка: {e}")
    else:
        print("Output:")
        print(stdout.decode())
        print("Error:")
        print(stderr.decode())
        # либо пишите в файл


приложил код обоих скриптов

@lolmandez12345 Я обновила ответ.
Отработайте первый вариант, убедитесь что в subprocess всё проходит штатно.
Добавьте stdout, stderr к Вашему вопросу.

не стоит использовать потоки с асинком

@ClarkDevlin Да, возможно. Насколько я понимаю asyncio вообще рекомендуемый способ решить это. Но до этого ещё далеко, @lolmandez12345 ещё не проверил subprocess (из этого вопроса может получиться что-то значимое, если автор будет готов разобраться). Посмотрим как пойдёт...

@AnnaBazueva , спасибо за помощь! в общем как я решил вопрос. я раскидал каждый из скриптов по отдельным папкам(просто ради красоты))), создал третий скрипт, основной и через треды запустил сначала TCP сервер, потом flask сервер. Все отлично работает! Получилось правда что-то значимое)

@lolmandez12345 Рада была помочь! Теперь Вам надо оформить ответом на свой же вопрос, своё решение. Возможно это кому-нибудь ещё пригодится, наверняка пригодится. Успехов!
